# MySQL list all available categories without repeating

Tags: php, mysql

Actually, I do not know how to properly describe what I'm really asking for. So, I have a list of records properly assigned to their categories.

There are 10 000 records, and I want to list only the categories which are used at least once.

I want to have something like:

```
Granades,
Pistols,
Parachutes
Binoculars
Helmets,
Knives
```

These categories are having at least one item inside of them. How to make a query which will not least 10 000 times these records, and SELECT only those which are present in this table ?

Sorry for bad explaining

Comment: Join on category table with a distinct category_id,category_name should do it

Comment: You can also use Group by `category_id,category_name `

Comment: thanks, I will try that in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to consider the following:

```
SELECT i.category
FROM items i
GROUP BY i.category
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This reads "group all items by category, and for all categories with at least one item, select the category".

(This form becomes more useful for `COUNT(*) > n` queries or other more complex conditionals on the grouping itself.)

In this case the result is also equivalent to the following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.category
FROM items i
```

Which is simply "find all the distinct categories across all items".

Comment: perfect! that's exactly what I want to do. thank you